# Mac : How to get custom URI parameters in application

Tags: objective-c, macos, uri-scheme

I've registered a URI Scheme "testscheme" for my application.
Also I've registered a URL handler in `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` **through**  `NSAppleEventManager`

**Below code to register the geturl handler**

```
NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
[appleEventManager setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

When I open "testscheme://some parameters" from browser for the first time(when my application is not running), OS opens my application.

If I check command line parameters I dont see "testscheme://some parameters" as command line arguments.

However, if I open the same url when my application is already running, I get URL in my GetURL handler registered with `NSAppleEventManager`.

**I wanted to get the testscheme url parameters in my application either by command line or by GetURL handler when it's launched first time.**

I also checked Mail.app, when i open `mailto:frank@wwdcdemo.example.com` in browser the parameters properly passed to Mail.app.
However, if I check the command line arguments at the same time using `ps -ef` for Mail.app, I don't see any parameters except the app path.

Please help me on this.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: What have command line parameters got to do with anything?  Don't you handle all URL-requests via `handleEvent`?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I got it working by registering handler in awakeFromNib, instead of applicationDidFinishedLaunching.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by registering GetURL eventHandler in `awakeFromNib` instead of `applicationDidFinishLaunching`